# preview-LaTeX: Specific scaling for graphics

Tags: emacs, auctex, wysiwyg

I'm using Emacs 23 with AUCTeX/preview-LaTeX for all my LaTeX editing. Mostly I am very happy with this, but I do not like the included graphics previewed in full size. For now my solution is to disable preview for floats and graphics, but what would be really nice would be to get a thumbnail preview of any included graphics.

My problem is that I cannot make sense of the description of `\PreviewMacro` included in the [`preview-latex` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex/Provided-commands.html), and in particular it is not clear to me if I can use a clever `\PreviewMacro` to generate a preview thumbnail for `\includegraphics...` by evaluating something like `\parbox{2cm}{\includegraphics...}` (all my graphics is scaled relative to `\linewidth`) or maybe `\includegraphics[width=2cm,...]`.
My only desperate attempt was

```
\PreviewMacro[{*?[{#{[#1]}{[width=2cm,{#1}]}}{[width=2cm]}{}}]{\includegraphics}
```

but this went nowhere.
Could this ever work -- and if so, how?